# What causes the difference between these boxes?

Tags: opengl, java, blender

I have recently started using Blender and I notice that the light (from my game) on default box is different from the one I downloaded. The below picture shows that.
[image]

They have the same normal direction in Blender.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left one has normal-per-side. Right one has normal-per-vertice. Causes of that - materials settings, smoothing groups/settings, manual disconnection of sides..

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my OBJreader and it works perfectly fine now